# Merging Create and Edit ActionResults into one using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

**I currently have 4 action methods:**

UserCreate - Get
UserCreate - Post

UserEdit - Get
UserEdit - Post

My goal is to somehow combine them do just be UserEdit. The only difference between the two is that UserCreate asks for Password and ConfirmPassword in the form. UserEdit does not. I ended up having to create 2 separate ViewModels for this: UserCreateViewModel, UserEditViewModel.

```
// GET: Users/Create
[Route("users/create")]
public IActionResult UserCreate()
{
    return View();
}

// POST: Users/Create
[Route("users/create")]
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> UserCreate(UserCreateViewModel vm)
{        
}

// GET: Users/Edit/5
[Route("users/edit/{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UserEdit(string id)
{
    return View(vm);
}

// POST: Users/Edit/5
[Route("users/edit/{id}")]
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> UserEdit(UserEditViewModel vm)
{
    return View(vm);
}
```

If keeping them separate is better and more MVC convention that is fine, but I just want to make sure there isn't some feature of MVC that I am not utilizing that can help me have only 2 Action methods, One view model for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep them separate. You aren't missing anything in MVC that is meant for working 'around' this so to say. Sure you could make it work but it strays from common api implementation for the sake of thinking they are similar actions. If it feels really bad you could use the same view model and code validations into page and server side (you couldn't rely on it being on the model as validation would now require two scenarios for one model) but if also split it out into two. It's cleaner.

Comment: Got it! it all makes sense to me now. Lets say I did create one GET function called UserEdit and made the id? optional. I could add a property called IsNew to the VM and simply check it for whether to show the Password and Confirm password fields. The problem here is that in my VM the [Required] annotation is on top of Password and ConfirmPassword so in a situation where the user is editing ModelState.IsValid will fail on POST. Make sense? Just want to make sure I have a good grasp of this even though I will most likely just keep everything separate with 2 separate VM's.

Comment: The final approach I am going with is two separate ViewModels and two separate functions. I was really trying to find a way to only have one single ViewModel since the forms are so similar, but validation is what messes me up as you were saying.

Comment: yes.as said keep it separate else it just messes up..need to write extra logic for checking. always follow SOLID principles.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can certainly have only 2methods using mvc feature:

You can create a method for create or edit user for GET type

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("users/useraddoredit/{id?}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UserEdit(string id)
{
  if(string.isNullorEmpty(id))
  {
    return View();
  }
  return View(vm);
}
```

You can create a method for POST type. Here create a new model UserViewModel which has all the attributes.

```
[Route("users/edit/{id}/{isUserEdit?}")]
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> UserEdit(UserViewModel vm, bool isUserEdit)
{
    if(isUserEdit)
    {
       return View(vm);
    }    
    else
    {
        //logic for add user
    }
}
```

PS:But its not recommended to use this approach.

Comment: PS:But its not recommended to use this approach. What approach? the entire thing you just explained? Do I still need 2 separate view models? One that shows the Create form and one that shows the Edit form?

Comment: yes.as said keep it separate else it just messes up..need to write extra logic for checking. always follow SOLID principles.

Comment: I get it. I appreciate you for showing me how I would combine it if I really wanted to. I'm glad I know about optional params now.

Comment: oh yea. glad to hear that. can you accept it as the answer coz i gave you the other way too.

Comment: The 'other' way isn't a way one should partake in, and it didn't explain why (since you are asking for the points instead of accepting what the OP did)

Comment: Explained it in the comments. Just put my extra effort in giving him insight into other way too.

Comment: @karthikmr One final question I have that maybe someone can answer. Lets say for another entity that I want to do CRUD on has the same exact form for Create and Edit. I am aware that I only need one ViewModel this time since all validation stays the same, but would I still want to keep 2 separate functions?

Comment: Yep! Two separate functions - always. They are at some point in time possibly using different HTTP Verbs as create and edit affect data differently (post vs put - POST is typically create and PUT for update, although thats more on the API side and you dont always see this in a form post, but you surely can. jQuery supports changing very and theres also x-http-method-override in a form that you can use in mvc http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HTTPPUTOrDELETENotAllowedUseXHTTPMethodOverrideForYourRESTServiceWithASPNETWebAPI.aspx